# How to filter on timespan in EF; no StringConvert?

Tags: entity-framework, where-clause, contains, timespan

In Entity Framework, I need to filter a SQL Server time field with text, so if a user types "4:" it should return 4:05, 4:00, 4:38 etc

For numbers there is `SqlFunctions.StringConvert` which gives me that possibility. But how can it be done for `TimeSpan`? There seems to be no overload for them.

Please advise

Comment: And what if they only type "4", or ":"? General advice: don't convert database values before filtering because it disables indexes. Convert the search term to a range check instead.

Comment: You could use `.ToString()` which is supported in L2E queries, but better take @GertArnold advice.

Comment: thanks for your input. in the end i parse it myself to a timespan and filter with that. thanks anyhow